PHP not getting attachments, what am I doing wrong?
Newbie question. I'm trying to get attached files in PHP, but I get only an empty $_FILES superglobal array.
Here's my test code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
                <title>Test file upload page</title>
        </head>
        <body>

<?php
        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
                $data = $_POST['text'];
                $file = isset($_FILES['file']) ? $_FILES['file'] : NULL;
                
                echo("<p>" . $data . "</p>");

                echo(print_r($_POST));
                echo(print_r($_FILES));
                
                if ($file != NULL) {
                        echo("<h1>There is an attachment.</h1>");
                        $fileContent = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
                        echo("<p>" . $fileContent . "<p>");
                } else {
                        echo("<h1>There is no attachment.</h1>");
                }
        } else {
?>

                <form action="formdata.php" method="post">
                        <textarea id="text" name="text" rows="4" cols="66" maxlength="300"></textarea>
                        <input id="file" type="file" name="file" onchange="" />
                        <!--button id="loadFile" onclick="">Upload</button-->
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>

<?php
        }       
?>

And here's all I get, weather I attach a file to input gadget or not.
Test text here.

Array ( [text] => Prova [file] => Meow_Meow.jpeg ) 1Array ( ) 1
There is no attachment.

I have briefly checked php.ini configuration, which I have not edited and has default Ubuntu values. File uploads are definitely on, so I don't think it may be a configuration error.
(base) dario@devmachine:~$ grep -Ri "file_uploads" /etc
/etc/php/8.3/cli/php.ini:; Default Value: -1 (Sum of max_input_vars and max_file_uploads)
/etc/php/8.3/cli/php.ini:file_uploads = On
/etc/php/8.3/cli/php.ini:max_file_uploads = 20
/etc/php/8.3/apache2/php.ini:; Default Value: -1 (Sum of max_input_vars and max_file_uploads)
/etc/php/8.3/apache2/php.ini:file_uploads = On
/etc/php/8.3/apache2/php.ini:max_file_uploads = 20

My final object is to understand how to pass file attachments from JS to PHP. But before being able to do that, I would like to understand how to get attachments from PHP to PHP too!

This feels like a likely dupe of this question . At least one issue is that your form tag is missing the enctype attribute, but that might not be the only problem. I'd suggest starting with the suggestions in the top answer, and then going from there.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php You're missing enctype="multipart/form-data".

Note you don't need echo(print_r($_FILES)); because print_r() already outputs what you want. Adding the echo wrapper also outputs the return value of print_r() which is simply true all the time.

Thank you all. Yes, enctype="multipart/form-data" fixes the form.
